# OverlapSphere for parallel arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, unity-game-engine, instantiation

How can i perform OverlapSphere for parallel arrays which detect when there is a overlapping of prefab gameObjects ?
Here is my code which generates these prefabs in random positions and sizes.

```
void Platform_Position_Scale_Generator(int i) {

    posX[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posY[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posZ[i] = 0;

    scaleX[i] = Random.Range(minScaleRange, maxScaleRange + 1);
    scaleY[i] = 1;
    scaleZ[i] = 1;

}

void Platform_Generator(int i) {

    platformPrefabPosition[i].x = posX[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].y = posY[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].z = posZ[i];

    Instantiate(platformPrefab, platformPrefabPosition[i], Quaternion.identity);
    platformPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleX[i], 1, 1);


}
```

Comment: Please be more clear on what you want, performing "OverlapSphere" doesn't exactly make sense to me.

Comment: Isnt it clear ?
Sorry. So like, i generate these random platforms. And since they will overlap because its randomly generated. How can i make it so they won't overlap each other ? Don't you need to do something like this ?
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html

Comment: So, basically you need to check if there's already an object where it's trying to instantiate the new object, and then return if there's already one there, correct? In this case you'd have to create a List<> of objects that have been instantiated, then you can either setup colliders and run collider checks, or do mathematical checks using the Renderer-bounds script you referenced.

Comment: Yea i think its something like that ? I don't actually know because ive never used it. I only heard from other people. I don't know what are the ways to check if there is a overlapping prefab gameobject. And if there is the prefab will delete itself and instantiate another one

Comment: Does the platformPrefab have a collider attatched to it? If so, what kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just create a script on your instantiated platform that uses the following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) 
    {
        if(collider.gameObject.tag == "platform") 
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note you will have to set the platforms game-object tag to "platform" and change OnTriggerEnter to OnCollisionEnter respectively if your gameobject is not set to Trigger.

What this script will do is trigger OnTriggerEnter/OnCollisionEnter when it collides with the other platform, and then delete itself.

Comment: Is it possible not to do this way ?

Comment: The other way would involve math based on the center-position of a game-object, which becomes much more complex.

Comment: Yes please, i would like to know that way.
But why can't you use the OverlapsSphere ?